# FullCalendar eventDrop not working between days

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I'm using FullCalendar v4 with resources. If I use the eventDrop function to drag and drop between resources everything is working fine. But if I use it to drag and drop between days in the month view it does nothing.

I use this code to check this function. I only get the four alerts if I drag and drop between the resources. The documentation says I can use the eventDrop function to get the new day. If I drag and drop between recourses and days at the same time it works, but only between days it does nothing. Can someone see what is going wrong?

```
eventDrop: function(info) {
var event = info.event;
var new_start = event.start;
var oldEvent = info.oldEvent;
var old_start = oldEvent.start;
var new_resource = info.newResource.id;
var old_resource = info.oldResource.id;
alert(new_resource);
alert(old_resource);
alert(new_start);
alert(old_start);
},
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/ExxzENr?&editable=true&editors=001 . The eventDrop event always fires, no matter how you drag. Can you make a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem?

Comment: Thanks! Your code helpt me to find the answer. I used this code: if (info.newResource) var new_resource = info.newResource.id;. This way it works. After testing with your code and reading the documentation again I saw that the resource is only given if the resource has changed. Now I check if this is not 'undefined'.